# Parametros dinamicos en Reporting Services

Tags: sql, ssrs, sql-server-2005

Actualmente estoy generando un reporte utilizando el SWL Server Business Inteligence Development Studio 2005 ya que es la version de reporting que usa mi cliente.

Su peticion es un reporte con 2 filtros, uno por region, y otro por tiendas, pero quiere que al seleccionar la región X el filtro de tiendas cargue unicamente las tiendas que pertenecen a esa región.

El filtro de regiones lo cargo con el siguiente query

```
select distinct(sitio), valor 
from cat_tiendas
order by valor
```

Y el de tiendas tiene el siguiente query

```
SELECT idTienda + ' ' + Observaciones AS descTienda
FROM cat_tiendas
WHERE (valor IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@valor, ',')))
ORDER BY valor
```

Pero a la hora de ejecutar el reporte me arroja que

```
la funcion o el proecidimiento dbo.FnSplit tiene demasiados argumentos
```

Pero si lo ejecuto manualmente el query me regresa sin problemas los campos del select

Alguien puede apoyarme a saber por donde es que esta yendo mal mi query.

Comment: Ok, ya revise el query y ya puedo hacer que se carguen las tiendas, pero solo puedo cargar una región a la vez. ¿Alguna idea de como puedo hacer para poder cargar mas de una region a la vez?

Comment: Una consulta, configuraste el parámetro `@valor` como multivalue?

Comment: @Lamak si, esta como multivalue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu parámetro `@valor` es multivalue, entonces no necesitas usar la función `FnSplit` para separar los valores. En SSRS (y sólo en este ambiente), basta que uses `IN`:

```
SELECT idTienda + ' ' + Observaciones AS descTienda
FROM cat_tiendas
WHERE valor IN (@valor)
ORDER BY valor
```

Comment: Esta practica la tenia por que en mi anterior proyecto el usuario asi manejaba sus reportes, con parametros multivalue pero ademas usaba la funcion split en sus queries, pero como tu dices, no es realmente necesaria esa función. Muchas gracias.